# Linux で IPv6 RH0 を有効にしたい

Tags: linux, ipv6

IPv6 の type 0 routing header に関するコードは RFC5095 により Linux から削除されました．[この記事](https://lwn.net/Articles/232781/) によると，RH0 はカーネル 2.6.20 で削除されたとのことです．

この度，少し試したいことがあり，この IPv6 RH0 を再度有効にしたいと考えております．

最新のカーネルで IPv6 RH0 に関するコードを復活させたカスタムカーネルを作成しインストールする方法はありませんでしょうか．

ざっと見たところ，[net/ipv6/addrconf.c の .accept_source_route](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a7fd20d1c476af4563e66865213474a2f9f473a4/net/ipv6/addrconf.c#L209) は関係してそうです．

もしくは，カーネル 2.6.19 をコンパイルし OS にインストールする方法はありませんでしょうか．

よろしくお願いします．